# How to License Check Android Wear app?

Tags: wear-os

I have seen samples how to do Licensing Check on ordinary App. But how do we do it for Android Wear app?

Anyone can guide me to the right direction?

Do we need license check on phone companion app only? Or do we need license check on wear device as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now (Jan 2016), Android Wear doesn't include this piece of Google Play Services, so you need to do the license check on the phone and pass the result over to the Wear device.

Comment: Ok thanks that's enlightenment I know how to do it then.

Comment: @rxlky But how did you solve problem for android wear 2.0? This android wear version may not be connected to the phone.

Comment: That's a good thought. Not sure yet since I didn't follow Wear 2.0 yet.